# Get relational data with Parse

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform

I have two classes, `Event`and `Category`. A `Category` has a series of `Events`, an `Event` has only one `Category`. I show `Category`s in a `ListView` correctly, but the problem comes when I try to show `Event`s. As they are shown when you click on a `Category`, I need to know which `Category` I clicked, so I pass it from my `CategoryFragment` to my `EventFragment` in form of a String with the name of the `Category`. My question is, how can I, with parse.com, show the events which correspond to the clicked category?

Comment: paste your sample code here

Answer (score 0):

One way that could work :

When you fetch the categories from Parse for populating the listview, store their object ids too. If you have created a custom object for items in the listview, then you can add a member say `String itemId;`

And when you are querying from Parse, while storing the objects, also store the object id into this member `itemId`.
This itemId can be passed to your eventFragment in a Bundle and then you can use it there to query the other details related to that eventId. Basically, when you click on any item in listview, you can call `adapter.getItem(position).getId` and pass it to the other fragment.

I hope this gives you some idea on how to go about.